# Items in a recyclerview aren't clickablle when recycler is placed inside a navigationview

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView embedded inside my navigation drawer. Problem is, items aren't clickable, nor can any effects(ripples et.al)be applied to them.

MainActivity.java

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/content_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_category_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Recycler Item layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_list_item_padding_horizontal_material"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_list_item_padding_horizontal_material"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_dialog_list_padding_vertical_material"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/abc_dialog_list_padding_vertical_material"
    android:background="@drawable/category_selector">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/post_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
        android:tint="#A0A0A0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/cat_text_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`drawable-v21\category_selector.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <ripple android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </item>

    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Code that populates the recycler via an adapter is working just fine.

**Adapter Code wherein the click listener is set**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onClick(View view, int position);
}

public CategoryAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
    mClickListener = (OnItemClickListener)context;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
    }
}

@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_menu_item_category, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position){

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mClickListener.onClick(v, position);
        }
    });
}
```

**Code inside MainActivity where clickhandler is defined**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_category_menu);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `android:foreground=?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` ? on the linearlayout

Comment: @Bhargav doesn't work

Comment: sorry I made a mistake you need to surround ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground with quotes like so `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @Bhargav doesn't work either